# TextPainter: painter.size different in Android vs. UnitTest

Tags: flutter

I am developing an App that does layouting. And running unit tests.

`TextPainter` returns different `Size`s for Android and Unit Tests. Sp does `Paragraph`.

Even if setting `fontFamily` to Roboto-Black accross devices and Unit Tests. (As Unit Tests seem not to use Roboto as default font.)

Below is the overview of calculated font sizes, with and without Roboto-Black:

**Sizes for word "test" using TextPainter.**

```
fontFamily: left empty, should be Roboto by default

Unit test: Size(400, 100) 
Android: Size(171, 117) ----------<< +1 width 
Chrome: Size(170, 117)


fontFamily: Roboto-Black

Unit test: Size(175, 120) ----------<< +3 height
Android: Size(175, 117)
Chrome: Size(175, 117)
```

**Sizes for word "test" using Paragraph.**

```
fontFamily: left empty, should be Roboto by default

Unit test: (200,200)
Android: (170.1, 117) -------<< + 0.2 width
Chrome: (169.9, 117)


fontFamily: Roboto-Black

Unit test: (174.31640625, 120) -------<< +3 height, +0.01640625 width
Android: (174.3, 117)
Chrome: (174.3, 117)
```

*Note:* The Unit Tests expects comparision with `174.31640625`, indicating that the result is not rounded as it should be? `174.3` fails the Unit Test.

**Devices Paragraph**

```dart
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          body: Builder(
            builder: ((context) {
              // ------------------------------------------------------

              const styleCustom =
                  TextStyle(fontFamily: 'myDefaultFont', fontSize: 100);
              const textCustom = Text('test', style: styleCustom);

              const style = TextStyle(fontSize: 100);
              const text = Text('test', style: style);

              // ------------------------------------------------------

              const constraints = ParagraphConstraints(width: 200);

              final builderCustom = ParagraphBuilder(ParagraphStyle(
                  fontFamily: styleCustom.fontFamily,
                  fontSize: styleCustom.fontSize));
              builderCustom.addText(textCustom.data!);
              final paragraphCustom = builderCustom.build();
              paragraphCustom.layout(constraints);
              final sizeCustom =
                  Size(paragraphCustom.longestLine, paragraphCustom.height);

              // ------------------------------------------------------

              final builder =
                  ParagraphBuilder(ParagraphStyle(fontSize: style.fontSize));
              builder.addText(text.data!);
              final paragraph = builder.build();
              paragraph.layout(constraints);
              final size = Size(paragraph.longestLine, paragraph.height);

              // ------------------------------------------------------

              // fontFamily: '',
              // Unit test: (200,200)
              // Android: (170.1, 117) -------<< + 0.2 width
              // Chrome: (169.9, 117)
              print(size);

              // fontFamily: 'myDefaultFont',
              // Unit test: (174.31640625, 120) -------<< +3 height, +0.01640625 width
              // Android: (174.3, 117)
              // Chrome: (174.3, 117)
              print(sizeCustom);

              return Column(
                children: [
                  text,
                  Text(size.toString()),
                  textCustom,
                  Text(sizeCustom.toString()),
                ],
              );
            }),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Devices TextPainter**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          body: Builder(builder: ((context) {

            // myDefaultFont == Roboto-Black

            const styleCustom =
                TextStyle(fontFamily: 'myDefaultFont', fontSize: 100);
            const textCustom = Text('test', style: styleCustom);

            const style = TextStyle(fontSize: 100);
            const text = Text('test', style: style);

            // fontFamily: '',
            // Unit test: (400, 100) -------<<
            // Android: (171, 117) -------<<
            // Chrome: (170, 117)
            var painter = _getPainter(text, style);
            print(painter.size);

            // fontFamily: 'myDefaultFont',
            // Unit test: (175, 120) -------<<
            // Android: (175, 117)
            // Chrome: (175, 117)
            final painterCustom = _getPainter(textCustom, styleCustom);
            print(painterCustom.size);

            return Column(
              children: [
                text,
                Text(painter.size.toString()),
                textCustom,
                Text(painterCustom.size.toString()),
              ],
            );
          })),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _getPainter(Text text, TextStyle style) {
    final TextPainter painter = TextPainter(
      text: TextSpan(children: [TextSpan(text: text.data!, style: style)]),
      textDirection: text.textDirection ?? TextDirection.ltr,
      maxLines: text.maxLines,
      textScaleFactor: text.textScaleFactor ?? 1.0,
      locale: text.locale,
      textAlign: text.textAlign ?? TextAlign.start,
      textHeightBehavior: text.textHeightBehavior,
      textWidthBasis: text.textWidthBasis ?? TextWidthBasis.parent,
    );

    painter.layout();
    return painter;
  }
}
```

**Unit Test**

*Note:* The Unit Tests expects comparision with `174.31640625`, indicating that the result is not rounded as it should be? `174.3` fails the Unit Test.

```dart
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

void main() {
  TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  test('paragraph', () async {
    final Future<ByteData> data = rootBundle.load('assets/Roboto-Black.ttf');
    final FontLoader fontLoader = FontLoader('myDefaultFont')..addFont(data);
    await fontLoader.load();

    const styleCustom = TextStyle(fontFamily: 'myDefaultFont', fontSize: 100);
    const textCustom = Text('test', style: styleCustom);

    const style = TextStyle(fontSize: 100);
    const text = Text('test', style: style);

    // ------------------------------------------------------

    const constraints = ParagraphConstraints(width: 200);

    final builderCustom = ParagraphBuilder(ParagraphStyle(
        fontFamily: styleCustom.fontFamily, fontSize: styleCustom.fontSize));
    builderCustom.addText(textCustom.data!);
    final paragraphCustom = builderCustom.build();
    paragraphCustom.layout(constraints);
    final sizeCustom =
        Size(paragraphCustom.longestLine, paragraphCustom.height);

    // ------------------------------------------------------

    final builder = ParagraphBuilder(ParagraphStyle(fontSize: style.fontSize));
    builder.addText(text.data!);
    final paragraph = builder.build();
    paragraph.layout(constraints);
    final size = Size(paragraph.longestLine, paragraph.height);

    print(size);
    print(sizeCustom);

    expect(size, const Size(200, 200));
    expect(sizeCustom, const Size(174.31640625, 120));
  });

  test('textpainter', () async {
    final Future<ByteData> data = rootBundle.load('assets/Roboto-Black.ttf');
    final FontLoader fontLoader = FontLoader('myDefaultFont')..addFont(data);
    await fontLoader.load();

    const style = TextStyle(fontSize: 100);
    const text = Text('test', style: style);

    const styleCustom = TextStyle(fontFamily: 'myDefaultFont', fontSize: 100);
    const textCustom = Text('test', style: styleCustom);

    var painter = _getPainter(text, style);

    final painterCustom = _getPainter(textCustom, styleCustom);

    print(painter.size);
    print(painterCustom.size);

    expect(painter.size, const Size(400, 100));
    expect(painterCustom.size, const Size(175, 120));
  });
}

_getPainter(Text text, TextStyle style) {
  final TextPainter painter = TextPainter(
    text: TextSpan(children: [TextSpan(text: text.data!, style: style)]),
    textDirection: text.textDirection ?? TextDirection.ltr,
    maxLines: text.maxLines,
    textScaleFactor: text.textScaleFactor ?? 1.0,
    locale: text.locale,
    textAlign: text.textAlign ?? TextAlign.start,
    textHeightBehavior: text.textHeightBehavior,
    textWidthBasis: text.textWidthBasis ?? TextWidthBasis.parent,
  );

  painter.layout();
  return painter;
}
```

**Question**

What parameters need changing to result in the same Sizes for the Devices and the Unit Tests?

Comment: does it happen with https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Paragraph-class.html too?

Comment: @pskink, Yes, same problem. I updated the question with the values for `Paragraph`. Also returning an unrounded / unusual width in the Unit Test which looks a bit suspicious.

Comment: @pskink  Injected the print in `performLayout()`. Unit tests do not print the size. But Chrome is the same for `TextPainter` and rounded-up to the next `integer` for `Paragraph. Android is substantially larger for both `TextPainter` and `Paragraph`. I am out of my depth here, not sure I am the right person to figure that out :( Thanks for your help!

Comment: so maybe see how `_textPainter` is created in line #96 and check if there are any differences in parameters (for example `textScaleFactor` in line 100)

Comment: @pskink All parameters being equal I suspect the difference is casued by the line height, which may also be adjusted by a mobile's manufacturer? See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the line height seems to be:

- 1.2 for Flutter unit tests.
- 1.17 for Flutter on (my) Android.

This explains the discrepancy for Roboto with font size of 100, which gets rendered with a height of 117 on Android but 120 in unit tests.

Setting line height to 1.0 results in `Size(175,100)`.

```dart
const style = TextStyle(
  fontFamily: 'Roboto',
  fontSize: 100,
  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
  textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
  decoration: TextDecoration.none,
  height: 1.0,
);

const text = Text('test', style: style);
const constraints = BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 200);

final p = RenderParagraph(
  TextSpan(text: text.data!, style: style),
  textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
);

p.layout(constraints);
final sizeCustom = p.size;

print(sizeCustom); // Size(175, 100)
```

At the moment, this seems the default style for Roboto on (my) Android mobile:

```dart
const style = TextStyle(
      fontFamily: 'roboto',
      fontSize: 14, // 100
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
      decoration: TextDecoration.none,
      height: 1.17,
    );

const textCustom = Text('test', style: style);
```